# How to show dialog box after the precondition checks?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I've got a bootstrap dialog box and I also have a related button - pressing on it will make the dialog box to be shown:

```
<button id="deployContractBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialogOfferContract"  onclick="offerContract()" type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled>Sign&Deploy Contract</button>
```

At the same time, when I click the button I've got a function that checks some preconditions and loading the errors string to the dialog box:

```
function offerContract()
    {
        document.getElementById("CreateContractDialogMessage").innerHTML = "";
        ErrorMsg = checkErrors();

            if (ErrorMsg != "")
            {
                $('#CreateContractDialogTitle').text("Error"); //show error headline
                document.getElementById("CreateContractDialogMessage").innerHTML = ErrorMsg;
                return;
            }
        $("#DeployContractForm").submit()

    }
```

What I need and I have no idea how to do it:
Check if there are errors (string is not empty).
   If there are errors --> show the dialog box and return from the function
else -->
do the submit.

In other words, how to show the dialog box from the javascript function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function offerContract()
    {
        document.getElementById("CreateContractDialogMessage").innerHTML = "";
        ErrorMsg = checkErrors();

            if (ErrorMsg != "")
            {
                $('#CreateContractDialogTitle').text("Error"); //show error headline
                document.getElementById("CreateContractDialogMessage").innerHTML = ErrorMsg;
                document.getElementById("closeButton").style.display = "block";
                $('#dialogOfferContract').modal('show');
                return;
            }
        $("#DeployContractForm").submit()

    }
```